# Google Crawls mostly Javascript files of my HTML website

Tags: seo, googlebot, crawl-errors, technical-seo, crawl-rate

I have an issue with my HTML static page website, and the issue in my HTML(DOM) crawls only 11% and javascript crawls 70%

[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Google Crawl javascript file mostly, you can see above image there is low crawling of an HTML page

Comment: I dont see a problem with that. Why do you expect something else? They are both parts of your site structure.

Comment: It is noteworthy that these requests are by the response (OK 200), not (304 not modified) in other words it appears as your server is not set up to put these in cache as assets that are not changing. The bot appears to be curious as to what may be changing in these files? It is not harmful, but you may want to go through the process of speeding up the site by allowing resources to be put into cache when they are resources that don't change.